# Routing issue in ASP.NET CORE 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using .Net Core 3.0.
This is basically as account verification module that sends user account confirmation email.
Below is the code i wrote to create a URL and send to user's email.
Confirmation link to be sent in the email is generated using LinkGenerator library and than concatenated with localhost to create a complete URL.
The URL sent in the email is created as below and **SendAccountConfirmationEmail** method is used to send email to the user.

```
[HttpPost("registerUser")]
    public IActionResult NewUser(UserModel userModel)
    {

        EmailSender emailSender = new EmailSender();
        string response = userDAL.NewUser(userModel).ToString();
        if (response != "EmailExists" && response != "UsernameExists")
        {
            EncryptDecrypt _encryptDecrypt = new EncryptDecrypt();
            string code = emailSender.GenerateEmailCode();
             string LinkEmail= _encryptDecrypt.Encrypt(response, "1359Mali_");
            string url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("ConfirmEmail", "User", new { email = LinkEmail, code = code });
            url = "https://localhost:44312" + url;

            bool EmailSent = emailSender.SendAccountConfirmationEmail(response,url);
            if (EmailSent == true)
            {
                userDAL.InsertUserEmailConfirmationCode(response, code);
            }
        }

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

I successfully recieve the email with redirection link in it but when i click on the link it opens in the browser and shows **Page Not Working** with **Http Error405**  and the debugger on the **ConfirmEmail** method is not hit.  ConfirmEmail method is given below :

```
 [HttpPost("ConfirmEmail/{email}/{code}")]
    public IActionResult ConfirmEmail( string email, string code)
    {
        EncryptDecrypt _encryptDecrypt = new EncryptDecrypt();
        string emailDecrypted = _encryptDecrypt.Decrypt(email, "1359Mali_");
        string codeDecrypted = _encryptDecrypt.Decrypt(code, "1359Mali_");
        string response = Convert.ToString(userDAL.VerifyCode(emailDecrypted, codeDecrypted));

        if (response.ToUpper() == "EMAILNOTCONFIRMED")
        {
            string message = "EMAILNOTCONFIRMED";
            return StatusCode(200, message);
        }
        else if (response.ToUpper() == "EMAILCONFIRMED")
        {
            //Call login medthod
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "An Error Occured";
            return StatusCode(200, message);
        }

    }
```

[image: Link recieved in email]

**StartUp.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();



        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```

Comment: hi Muhammad Ali, welcome to stackoverflow! something is bugging me, so.. the link in the email will always result in a `GET` request, but you define `POST` request (defined at `[HttpPost("ConfirmEmail/{email}/{code}")]`) on the routing, and then you got HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed)... right?

Comment: Thanks alot Sir for welcoming me and for the correct answer. Its working now with HTTPGET :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a browser opens on a page. That is a Get request. So you should change:

```
[HttpPost("ConfirmEmail/{email}/{code}")]
public IActionResult ConfirmEmail( string email, string code)
```

to:

```
[HttpGet("ConfirmEmail/{email}/{code}")]
public IActionResult ConfirmEmail( string email, string code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpPost is not possible in email links. Please either update your action to receive GET requests by marking it as HttpGet.

If you want your action to receive HttpPost requests also, then you can add both HttpGet as well as HttpPost, so action will receive both GET and POST requests.